# Are there any GUI-builder, similiar to Swing Builder, for java-fx?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx

I've been using Swing a lot but I am trying out JavaFX for the first time. For Swing, I used gui-builder a lot, because in my opinion, design is very time-consuming and drag-drop is very time efficient.

I've seen some examples using XML, but I only want to use GUI-builder to drag and drop buttons, without using XML, just like Swing-builder (PLUGIN).

Is there anything similar to JavaFX? For Eclipse, and/or Netbeans?

Comment: *" For Swing, I used gui-builder a lot, because in my opinion, design is very time-consuming and drag-drop is very time efficient"* Emmm yeah, but builders typically generate very poor quality code. Not to mention that generated code is usually not portable between IDE's. I used to think in the same way as you do but the experience teached me that hand-code is simpler, cleaner and more portable than auto-generated code.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [JavaFX SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html).

The ouput is FXML (XML) but you don't have to look at it if you don't like it.

Comment: No, or at least none that I know of. And it is not needed, FXML has several advantages..

Comment: In my opinion you should do as much as possible in FXML for your design. FXML is easier to read than 100 lines of code which creates buttons, panes etc.